# Can i ignore child's namespaces from @XmlRootElement

Tags: xml, kotlin, namespaces, xml-namespaces, package-info

I'm using Kotlin 1.3, Java 8 and Spring 4.0+.

Just i want to attach a namespace only to `<HELLO>`, not to childs of it.
But, when i define the namespace using @XmlRootElement for `<HELLO>` then `<HI>` also get a default namespace even i don't define any namespace.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "HELLO", namespace = "http://www.hello.net")
public class Hello {

    @XmlElement(name = "HI")
    protected Hi hi;
```

then

```
    <HELLO xmlns="http://www.hello.net">
        <HI xmlns=""></HI>
    </HELLO>
```

Is there any way for removing `xmlns=""` (a default namespace) from `<HI>`?

> **FYI (after finished with an answer):**
>
> I'm developing with Kotlin 1.3. I need to use Java Classes generated
>   from XML using xjc(JAXB), because program(API) spec is handled by XML
>   from external client which will communicate with the APIs.
>
> When use xjc without -npa option there is a **package-info.java** for
>   apply a same namespace on all of classes generated with just two loc and i exported these classes on my project.
>   (ref:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html)
>
> I thought that **@XmlSchema(namespace = "namespace1") in package-info.java** works well when i register JaxbAnnotationModule() in XmlMapper(with JacksonXmlModule). But, It seems Jackson XmlMapper doesn't fully support xml annotations.
>
> You can solve this problem with below answer or adding XmlMarshaller that add an xmlns to XML.
>
> **jackson-dataformat-xml does not support the namespace of package level : https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/18**

Comment: I'm sorry, but how are you using Kotlin 1.6? 1.3 was just released, 1.6 is far from even having alpha dev done on the release

Comment: @zoe sorry, edited. I used Kotlin 1.3. I confused with JVM version 1.6 Kotlin uses

Comment: Found an interesting solution: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/18#issuecomment-446546133

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to inherit the `http://www.hello.net` in the XML output then you'll need to give it that namespace.

Comment: Oh my gosh, it was a silly question. I didn't know it will smartly inherit a namespace. Thanks for quick replying on silly question.

Comment: Oh, but as your solution, i should write that namspace to all child classes of "Hello". Is there any solution? for just cut it on "Hello" class level?

Comment: I'm answering out of XML knowledge rather than Java knowledge,  so I don't know if there's a convenient way to say "just inherit the namespace" with your particular toolkit.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your answer :)